# textElement markup styled for text out of FIELDS

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to pregenerate styled text out of the result from database:

Should be

```
Red Text Black Text
```

and not

```
<font color=\"red\">Red Text</font> Black Text
```

When I use a fix textFieldExpression all works fine, but when using

```
<![CDATA[$F{TEXT}]]>
```

it only shows me the text which I got from the database. 
Setting "Evaluation Time" to "Band" didn't change anything.

Attached the jrxml file of a short example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.10.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.10.0-unknown  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Fields_Styled" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e4874d20-5d51-429a-81c9-a12ce399a0b8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Oracle Local"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select '<font color="red">Red Text</font> Black Text' text from dual
        union all select '<font color="red">Red Text  2</font> Black Text 2 <QUARTAL>' text from dual
        union all select '<font color="red">Red Text  3</font> Black Text 3' || lpad('XX',200,'YYYY AB') text from dual
        union all select '<font color="red">Red Text  4</font> Black Text 4' || lpad('XX',3900,'YYYY AB') text from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="TEXT" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.sql.field.column.name" value="TEXT"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="8142a933-8456-4ad5-bf30-57872e0be50a"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<font color=\"red\">Red Text</font> Black Text"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="20" width="290" height="30" uuid="9b43d761-db44-48a8-ade1-93c8e146f9d9"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TEXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Removing the \ helped for my example .. but not with the query which resulted a longer string ...

Comment: Got my error ... had some not replaced tags like <QUARTAL> which would be replaced in the final string